# How to generate dynamic graphs using php while getting data from sql?|

Tags: php

hello
i need help about how to create a dynamic graph that gets values from sql depending on different dates

Samuel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pie Chart Drawing in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147/pie-chart-drawing-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with php or Pear but I do with GraphViz and it can do a lot. Creating graphics from about any data source.

So this graphviz wrapper in php might be helpful to you : http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.images.image-graphviz.example.php

more introduction information [here](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~cjwallac/viz/)

from that second link you can find the following script:

```
    <?php
// input is $name - the person to highlight in the hierarchy
// connect to the database
   if(!($dblink=mysql_connect("shares.cems.uwe.ac.uk","cwstudent","cwstudent"))) {
     print("mysql_connect failed<br>\n");
     exit;
   }

   if(!(mysql_select_db("Emp",$dblink))) {
     print("cannot connect to database $db");
     exit;
   }
// get the hierarchy data
   $query = "select e.ename as ename, m.ename as mname from emp e , emp m where e.mgr = m.empno;";
   if(!($dbresult = mysql_query($query,$dblink))) {
        print("<b>query failed</h4><br>\n");
        print(mysql_error() . "<br>\n");
   }

   $f .= "digraph hier {\n";
   if (isset($name) ) $f .= " $name [fillcolor=red1, shape=box];\n";
   while($rep=mysql_fetch_object($dbresult)) {
       $f .= "$rep->mname  -> $rep->ename; \n"; 
   }
   $f .="}";
   mysql_close($dblink);
//set output to be GIF
   header("Content-type: image/gif");
//execute the dot program and pass thru the output back to the client
   passthru("echo '$f' | /usr/local/graphviz/bin/dot -Tgif ");


?>
```

For more detail on how to program it exactly you should get this question to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by graphs?

KeesDjijk's answer is valid for the correct meaning of graphs (i.e. a set of nodes and connections) but do you mean charts like you get in spreadsheet programs? If so, have a look at [jpgraph](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjpgraph.net%2F&rct=j&q=jpgraph&ei=AHZiTdKSAsLB4gaNzZn_CQ&usg=AFQjCNFZu_hTcgWTX-GwVMcUEGWyt88flw&sig2=_mgnaIBRDWNkN6li2_H0Nw&cad=rja).